# mt.exe not manifesting

Tags: c, visual-studio, manifest

I'm trying to get my program to pop up UAC and ask to be run as admin when it's executed using a manifest file.

I'm using the following command...

```
mt.exe -manifest hi.exe.manifest -outputresource:hi.exe;1
```

The command goes through but when I actually run the executable it doesn't ask for admin privleges. The manifest file is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
   <ms_asmv2:trustInfo xmlns:ms_asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft- 
     com:asm.v2">
      <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X64"
     name="hi"
     type="win32"/> 
      <description>Description of your application</description> 
      <ms_asmv2:security>
         <ms_asmv2:requestedPrivileges>
            <ms_asmv2:requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false">
            </ms_asmv2:requestedExecutionLevel>
         </ms_asmv2:requestedPrivileges>
      </ms_asmv2:security>
   </ms_asmv2:trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Did you disable UAC? If you did, then it won't ask you for admin privleges even if the manifest says to.

Comment: It is very sloppy.  The line break in `urn:schemas-microsoft-` stops it from working.